# Go structure for unmarshalling a JSON array

Tags: json, go

So I have some JSON (courtesy of the PetFinder API) that has a JSON array "pet".  I want to unmarshal from it, using the "encoding/json" package, a slice of pet structs.  **What would this kind of structure look like?** I can't find any examples of how the unmarshall function handles JSON arrays.

Here's what I was planning to do once I had a proper struct:

```
pfetch := new(PetsFetcher) // where PetsFetcher is the struct im asking for
err := json.Unmarshal(body, &pfetch)
```

And here's the json that is in body (in the form of a slice of ascii bytes):

```
{
  "petfinder": {
    "lastOffset": {
      "$t": 5
    },
    "pets": {
      "pet": [
        {
          "options": {
            "option": [
              {
                "$t": "altered"
              },
              {
                "$t": "hasShots"
              },
              {
                "$t": "housebroken"
              }
            ]
          },
          "breeds": {
            "breed": {
              "$t": "Dachshund"
            }
          }
    },
        {
          "options": {
            "option": {
              "$t": "hasShots"
            }
          },
          "breeds": {
            "breed": {
              "$t": "American Staffordshire Terrier"
            }
          },
          "shelterPetId": {
            "$t": "13-0164"
          },
          "status": {
            "$t": "A"
          },
          "name": {
            "$t": "HAUS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your PetsFetcher struct(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no idea what those `$t` attributes are doing there in your JSON, so let’s answer your question with a simple example. To unmarshal this JSON:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "options": [
    {
      "key": "a",
      "value": "b"
    },
    {
      "key": "c",
      "value": "d"
    },
    {
      "key": "e",
      "value": "f"
    },
  ]
}
```

You need this `Data` type in Go:

```
type Option struct {
    Key   string
    Value string
}

type Data struct {
    Name    string
    Options []Option
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  To make life even simpler, I found this handy library someone made https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson.

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshal a javascript array into a slice. The marhsal/unmarshalling rules are described under `Marshal` in the [json package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

To unmarshal keys that look like "$t", you'll have to annotate the struct that it'll unpack into.

For example:

```
type Option struct {
    Property string `json:"$t,omitempty"`
}
```

It may be that the $t that appear are a mistake, and are supposed to be keys in a dictionary.